# Trying to get firebase values out of Promise

Tags: firebase, react-native, geofire

I am new to react native and I am having hard times getting values out of a firebase query inside a promise.

I tried to setState in the promise but the console returns : TypeError: _this2.setState is not a function.

```
_getActivites() {
      const latitude = 42.297761;
      const longitude = 4.636235;
      const radius = 5;

  var keys = [];
  var activitesToState = [];

  const firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref("activites_locations/");
  const geoFire = new GeoFire(firebaseRef);
  var geoQuery;
  var activites = [];

  geoQuery = geoFire.query({
    center: [latitude, longitude],
    radius: radius
  });

  geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance) {
    keys.push(key);
  });

  geoQuery.on("ready", function() {
    var promises = keys.map(function(key) {
      return firebaseRef.child(key).once("value");
    });
    Promise.all(promises).then((snapshots) => {
      snapshots.forEach(function(snapshot) {
        activites.push(snapshot.val());
      });
      this.setState({
        activitesState: activites,
      })
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });

  });

};

componentDidMount() {
  firebase.auth().signInAnonymously()
    .then(() => {
      this.setState({
        isAuthenticated: true,
      });
  });

  this._getActivites();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are losing the value of `this` in your function calls. You should bind your calls by updating your functions to arrow functions. You can also stop prevent the lost of `this` by setting it as a variable in the scope of your function.

Refactoring your code you could have something like this:

```
_getActivites = () => { // change to arrow function
  const that = this;  // capture the value of this
  const latitude = 42.297761;
  const longitude = 4.636235;
  const radius = 5;

  var keys = [];
  var activitesToState = [];

  const firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref('activites_locations/');
  const geoFire = new GeoFire(firebaseRef);
  var geoQuery;
  var activites = [];

  geoQuery = geoFire.query({
    center: [latitude, longitude],
    radius: radius
  });

  geoQuery.on('key_entered', (key, location, distance) => { // change to arrow function
    keys.push(key);
  });

  geoQuery.on('ready', () => { // change to arrow function
    var promises = keys.map((key) => { // change to arrow function
      return firebaseRef.child(key).once('value');
    });
    Promise.all(promises).then((snapshots) => {
      snapshots.forEach((snapshot) => {
        activites.push(snapshot.val());
      });
      that.setState({ activitesState: activites }); // use "that" instead of "this"
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  });
}
```

Here is a great [article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/what-to-do-when-this-loses-context-f09664af076f) about `this` and it losing its context.

Comment: Thank you so much for your code and the article, it really helped me lot ! Knowing that I am a beginner, do you think I wrote my code the best way (performance wise) to query my data using firebase and geofire ? Do you think I can make some improvements ?

Comment: It looks good. I like your use of a Promise.all, so that you are only setting state once.

Comment: Thanks ! And thank you again for helping me improving myself with React Native.